# How to find the current season through any iOS API?

Tags: ios

Is there anyway in iOS to find the current season (Spring, Summer, Winter, Fall) of the current location?

Seasons are different in different part of the world. I might experience different season in Australia when during the same time season in USA is something else.

Any weather API or something that returns the season of that place?

Comment: it'd be pretty simple to figure out. use normal US seasons, then check latitude. if below the equator, then winter->summer, fall->spring, etc...

Comment: I'm not aware of an API, but you should be able to do it with relatively simple logic in a method in your app.

Comment: @MarcB It's not that simple. Firstly, the changeover dates don't match up (eg Australia doesn't hit winter on exactly the same day as the UK hits summer). Secondly some places near the equator, where there is little seasonal variation, eg Mauritius, have only Summer and Winter; never Spring/Autumn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the coordinates of the user's current location:

```
CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
lm.delegate = self;
lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
[lm startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [lm location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord = [location coordinate];
```

Then get the current date:

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
```

That's all you need, I think. Determine if the user is above or below the equator, and store the dates of season changes as constants.

Comment: The dates and times vary from year to year. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox for a table of upcoming years.

Answer (score 4):

I need to know the current season in my application and I saw your post.

So, even if it's an old post, there is my answer and my code.

I get the coordinates of the user and I compare the latitude to know if the user is in the Northern Hemisphere (latitude between 0° and 90°) or in the Southern Hemisphere (latitude between 0° and -90°).
After that, I fixed dates for the seasons and compare date with the current date.

Have Fun :

```
- (void)currentSeason
{
    NSCalendar* myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [myCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.hour = 12;

    // Current year
    NSInteger currentYear = components.year;

    // Today
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    // First Day of the year
    components.month = 1;
    components.day = 1;
    components.year = currentYear;
    NSDate *firstDayDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Spring Date
    components.month = 3;
    components.day = 21;
    components.year = currentYear;
    NSDate *springDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Summer Date
    components.month = 6;
    components.day = 21;
    components.year = currentYear;
    NSDate *summerDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Autumn Date
    components.month = 9;
    components.day = 23;
    components.year = currentYear;
    NSDate *autumnDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Winter Date
    components.month = 12;
    components.day = 22;
    components.year = currentYear;
    NSDate *winterDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Last Day of the year
    components.month = 12;
    components.day = 31;
    components.year = currentYear;
    NSDate *lastDayDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Current Location
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [location coordinate];

    // North Hemisphere
    if (coord.latitude > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"North Pole");

        // Settings the background image
        if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:firstDayDate lastDate:springDate] || [self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:winterDate lastDate:lastDayDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Winter");
        }
        else if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:springDate lastDate:summerDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Spring");
        }
        else if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:summerDate lastDate:autumnDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Summer");
        }
        else if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:autumnDate lastDate:winterDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Autumn");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"South Pole");

        // Settings the background image
        if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:firstDayDate lastDate:springDate] || [self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:winterDate lastDate:lastDayDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Summer");
        }
        else if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:springDate lastDate:summerDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Autumn");
        }
        else if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:summerDate lastDate:autumnDate])
        {
            NSLog(@"Winter");
        }
        else if ([self isDate:today inRangeFirstDate:autumnDate lastDate:winterDate])
        {
           NSLog(@"Spring");
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date inRangeFirstDate:(NSDate *)firstDate lastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate
{
    return ([date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedDescending) && ([date compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedAscending);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something very similar currently but the dates can vary by a few days each year so its not exactly correct.

Comment: It’s a very old implementation without any persistance. The best would be to have a service or a JSON data file (or whatever) to old the different season date for many years and build the logic around this.